# HackerRank Staircase Python

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a problem in HackerRank and I am having an issue with my submission. My code works in PyCharm but HackerRank is not accepting my submission.

Here is the problem I am trying to solve: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/staircase

Here is my code:

```
def staircase(num_stairs):
    n = num_stairs - 1
    for stairs in range(num_stairs):
        print ' ' * n, '#' * stairs
        n -= 1
    print '#' * num_stairs
staircase(12)
```

Any ideas why HackerRank is not accpeting my answer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your output is incorrect; you print an empty line before the stairs that should not be there. Your `range()` loop starts at `0`, so you print `n` spaces and zero `#` characters on the first line.

Start your `range()` at 1, and `n` should start at `num_stairs - 2` (as Multiple arguments to `print()` adds a space:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def staircase(num_stairs):
    n = num_stairs - 2
    for stairs in range(1, num_stairs):
        print(' ' * n, '#' * stairs)
        n -= 1
    print('#' * num_stairs)
```

You can simplify this to one loop:

```
def staircase(num_stairs):
    for stairs in range(1, num_stairs + 1):
        print(' ' * (num_stairs - stairs) + '#' * stairs)
```

Note that I use concatenation now to combine spaces and `#` characters, so that in the last iteration of the loop zero spaces are printed and `num_stairs` `#` characters.

Last but not least, you could use the [`str.rjust()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) (short for “right-justify”) to supply the spaces:

```
def staircase(num_stairs):
    for stairs in range(1, num_stairs + 1):
        print(('#' * stairs).rjust(num_stairs))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [rjust](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rjust) to justify the string to the right:

```
def staircase(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
         print(("#" * i).rjust(n))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution

```
n = int(raw_input())
s = '#'
for i in xrange( 1 , n+1):
    print " "*(n-i) + s*i
```

Answer (score 2):

first, create a list, then print with join `\n'`

```
def staircase(n):
    print("\n".join([' ' * (n-x) + '#' * x for x in range(1, n+1)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def staircase(n):
    for i in range(0, n): # n rows 
        print(' '*(n-i-1) + '#'*(i+1)) # first print n-i-1 spaces followed by i '#'


n = int(input())
staircase(n)
```

Comment: Please respond to OPs question: "Any ideas why HackerRank is not accepting my answer?" Is your suggestion that there's a problem with OP's code which would be solved by using this code instead?

Answer (score 1):

its look like secondary diagonal

```
 def staircase(n):
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range (n):
                if i+j == n-1:
                    print(" "*j+"#"*(n-j))
```

output-

```
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(n):
    result = ' '*(n-i-1) +('#')*(i+1)
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error until I replaced the comma with a plus sign:

```
print(' ' * (n - i - 1) + '#' * (i + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Understanding the problem is 80% of the solution. The requirement states the min/max total of stairs.

```py
"""
Prints a staircase with a total number of stairs
Note: total number of stairs must be between 1 and 100 inclusive, as per requirements
"""
def staircase(n):
    if n < 1 or n > 100:
        print("Error: Total number of stairs must be between 1, 100 inclusive!")
    else:
        for x in range(1, n+1):
            print(" " * (n - x) + "#" * x )

#-----------------------
staircase(0)
Error: Total number of stairs must be between 1, 100 inclusive!

staircase(101)
Error: Total number of stairs must be between 1, 100 inclusive!

staircase(4)
   #
  ##
 ###
####
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def staircase(n):
    space = n-1
    for i in range(n):
        x = i + 1
        print(" " * space + "#" * x)
        space -= 1
```

Comment: Might be good to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

one more solution:

```
def staircase(n):
    for i in reversed(range(n)):
        print(i*' '+(n-i)*'#')
```

Comment: Why do you think this is a good solution? What does it do that the others offered here do not? Please [edit] and explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the sep argument of print from ' ' to '', and your answer will be correct

```
def staircase(n):    
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(' ' * (n-i), '#' * (i), sep='')
```

The answer you submitted is not accepted because the default print settings adds an empty space in front of the printouts, and one of the question requirements is for there to have no spaces in the output.

The default sep in print is a space character i.e. ' '.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the cleanest way to write the code, but it works:

```
print('\n'.join(' ' * (n - i) + '#' * i for i in range(1, n + 1)))
```

Answer (score -1):

**Another Answer**

```
    H = int(input())
    for i in range(1,H+1):
       H = H - 1
       print(' '*(H) + ('#'*(i)))
```

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use while loop also.

```
import sys
n1=int(raw_input())-1
n2=1

while n1>=0:
    print " "*n1,"#"*n2
    n1=n1-1
    n2=n2+1
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 def staircase(n):
     for in range(i,n+1):
          print str("#"*i).rjust(n)
```

Comment: please add some point and why you did so explanation. only code is not really appreciated.